# Where to Find the Level 1 Focus Rules for Hit Locations

Tags: the-dark-eye, locational-damage, the-dark-eye-5

I am trying to find the Level Focus rules that are talked about on page 49 of the Aventurian Bestiary under the special rules of the Giant Stag Beetle.

> *Weak Spot:* The giant stag beetle has PRO 2 on the belly, PRO 0 at the base of the leg joints. For more information about targeting these areas, see the Level 1 Focus Rules for Hit Locations, in the *Aventurian Compendium*.

Now, I have looked all around for these rules, and I just can't seem to find it anywhere...

Where is this *Aventurian Compendium*, and what page are they on?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I edited your question to specify which Focus Rules you are asking about. If those are not the rules you can't find, feel free to roll back or edit that in. Did you take a look in the Aventurian Compendium already?

Comment: @Patta Yes, the edit is fine. As for the _Aventurian Compendium_ I haven't been able to find it. Do you know where it is? Is it in English?

Comment: Hey there! We're working on potentially relabeling some questions related to The Dark Eye. In order to help us out, can you tell us what edition of DSA this question is about? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For future reference, the rules have been released in an English copy of *Adventuria Compendium*. They can be found on page 128-132.

Answer (score 3):

The [Kickstarter](https://twitter.com/darkeyerpg/status/931522384070356992) for the english version of the (5th edition) compendium started on November 17th 2017 and was fully funded within 24 hours, but naturally it is not yet released. That is why you can't find the rules anywhere. Up until now, the rules only exist in the german version, but the english version might still take some time after the campaign is over.

Comment: Until someone can give me the rules translated, I will accept this as the answer.

Comment: I would have done that (At least I think I have the German Compendium somewhere), but I am not sure if I am allowed to post that here, sorry.

Comment: You should be able to quote the rules like I did above, yes?

Comment: You could also link to the german Ulisses Rule Wiki Page for the [Hit Locations](http://www.ulisses-regelwiki.de/index.php/Trefferzonen.html)

Comment: @Cohnal Can you post that as the answer and I will mark it as such.

Comment: @Cohnal Thanks for pointing that out - the Rule Wiki Page (in German) is a great online resource and also includes creatures, classes and much more.

Answer (score 3):

**The english Aventuria Compendium is not yet released.**

Ulisses US has launched a [kickstarter campaign](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1216685848/aventuria-compendium-the-dark-eye-rpg) to fund the compendium. It is alreadyfunded (thought as of the moment of writing not all stretch goals are funded). There is no official release date yet, but the kickstarter goals (including the compendium and armory) have an estimated delivery of March or May 2018.

Until then you could try the german language version or the german language [Ulisses Rules Wiki](http://www.ulisses-regelwiki.de/index.php/Trefferzonen.html). If you are able to read it.

Comment: slight note to attention: you might update this in the new light.